# Suggestions on handling icons on Android

Tags: android, performance

So I'm trying to figure out, I have about 1,000 different icons that I will have in my app that will distinguish users. Should I have these stored as resources or should I have them saved in a webserver and pull them when needed?

Just trying to figure out what is most efficient .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is app size be a problem for you? What is the total size of your 1000 icons? I guess just a few MB?
2. Will network performance hinder user experience? eg. user can't see icons when they are still being downloaded from webserver. If you store as resources you won't have this problem
3. Will the 1000 icons being updated frequently? If so it might be easier to update through internet. If not being updated, why bother storing in a webserver?
4. Storing in webserver will cost extra money for network transfer, while it's free to store as resources

Hope it helps you decide!

Comment: Yes this helped me understand on how to handle the icons better. Thanks!